# Kotlin @JvmStatic functions provided by a default implementation on an interface

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin, I can use a `@JvmStatic` annotation to allow `companion object` members to be called statically from Java:

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
class Foo {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun bar() {}
    }
}
```

**Java**

```java
Foo.bar();
```

`companion object` can also implement interfaces:

**Kotlin**

```
interface Bar {
    fun bar(){}
}

class Foo {
    companion object : Bar
}
```

But using this approach, I cannot call `bar` statically in Java:

**Java**

```java
Foo.bar(); // error
Foo.Companion.bar(); // OK
```

Is there a way to provide a `@JvmStatic` function that is provided by a default implementation on an interface?

Comment: Interfaces should be allocated and their members always accessed through the allocated object. `companion object : Bar` is an actual (static) allocation of an object that  implements the interface. Method name collision is probably what prevents java requiring also `.Companion.bar()`